# How to convert _Uint8ArrayView to List<String>

Tags: postgresql, dart, uuid

In postgresql I have a column:

```sql
account_ids uuid[] NOT NULL DEFAULT array[]::uuid[],
```

when I receive data from database in my server app that using `postgres: ^2.6.1` package, I'm getting this:

```sql
_Uint8ArrayView ([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 134])
```

I was expecting to get an empty list of uuids in type of String.

How to convert `_Uint8ArrayView` to `List<String>` to get an empty list or something like this:

```dart
<String>['aff7e72c-0b4c-47af-b4de-5aecfc723001']
```

Comment: That's probably dart-specific. When requested from command line it returns expected: `psql -c "select * from sample"` output: `{aff7e72c-0b4c-47af-b4de-5aecfc723001}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Postgres Dart package, but I think the `dart:convert` library should be able to help you here.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/Utf8Decoder-class.html

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

final utf8Decoder = utf8.decoder;
final arr = [72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 33];

final str = utf8Decoder.convert(arr);
print(str); // Hello!

final alternativeStr = utf8.decode(arr);
print(alternativeStr); // Hello!
```

Of course, depending on the encoding returned by Postgres, you might need another function from `dart:convert`.

Answer (score 0):

We can see the definition of `_Uint8ArrayView` in [typed_data_patch.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/f340a23cde5247b001e9fb0fbd52d7b84f9f32dc/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/typed_data_patch.dart#L4399-L4401) in the Dart SDK:

```dart
final class _Uint8ArrayView extends _TypedListView
    with _IntListMixin, _TypedIntListMixin<Uint8List>
    implements Uint8List {
...
```

The key there is `implements Uint8List`. So it's simply a matter of casting the result to `Uint8List` and treating it accordingly.

Following is an example of converting a `_Uint8ArrayView` to a `String`:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main() {
  var buffer = Uint8List.fromList([0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45]).buffer;
  var sublist = buffer.asUint8List(1, 3);
  print(sublist.runtimeType);

  var list = sublist as Uint8List;
  var str = utf8.decode(list);
  print('str = $str');
}
```

Output:

```
_Uint8ArrayView
str = BCD
```